# php regular expression name not start with space

Tags: php, regex, space

I need a regular expression for my name which should contain A-Za-Z\s and not start with space.

```
if (preg_match("/[[[:space:]]A-Za-z\s] | [^(A-Za-z\s)]/",$city  )) {
         error
}
```

but I does not work. I need help. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
preg_match("/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z\s]*$/", $city)
```

This breaks down to:

1. Match anything of `[A-Za-z]`
2. then match anything of `[A-Za-z\s]` arbitrarily often.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do:

```
if (preg_match("/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z\s]+$/", $city)) {
    // OK
}
```